# Is RRDtool good for monitoring website user actions?

Tags: php, rrdtool

Client wants graphical representation of users online, registrations/logins/logouts graphics etc. Is RRDtool ok for it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As long as you are focusing on a limited number of data sources, rrdtool is perfect for this.

Good: Number of people logged into the system over the course of a day.

Bad: Individual login and logoff times for each user of the system.

cheers
tobi

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question.. It depends on what you want to do. While RRDtool is a great tool, it isn't a trivial task to set it up and manage it's needs.

If you are just wanting to produce nice looking graphs in a way that's more straight forward, consider looking at JpGraph.  http://www.aditus.nu/jpgraph/features_gallery.php

Comment: I want RRDTool because it is really easy log data and I have almost nothing to do to get nicely looking graphs.

Comment: @Kirzilla doesn't that answer your own question? You want RRDTool?

Comment: @Kirzilla The best way to see if it's going to work for you is to just try it.  It wouldn't be my first choice for what you are describing, but it certianly is usable for it.